# HOW TO dump database with encoded password

Tags: mysql

I have database in which table stores encoded password.after dumping that and aging importing it changes password.how to resolve this to have same password?

Comment: So you have a table with multiple columns. You like to back up that table. But if you restore the table, you do not want one particular column (the one with the password) to be restored? - I do not understand what you mean by "and aging importing it changes password". Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Actually MySQL has the functionality to generate random password on import, this can be changed if you are able to find the root user settings and changing it from there, ironically its the best thing to import via .txt file and afterwards changing the permissions.